# NumberFormatException printing before necessary error

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, numberformatexception

I'm getting the following results when I run the following section of my code it works well it just appears to print the `NumberFormatException` before running the do-while loop even though that isn't an option in my code at least not intended. Please help me to understand this error thank you!

Console output:
Enter the number of dice to draw (re-roll) - up to 3: 2
Enter the index numbers (0 to 3) separated by a space of the dice you wish to draw: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
Try again
Enter the index numbers (0 to 3) separated by a space of the dice you wish to draw: 0 1

Rolling the dice...

```java
int[] tempIndex = new int[hands.getDrawNum()];
boolean tryAgain = true;

do {
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter the index numbers (0 to 3) separated by a space "
                + "of the dice you wish to draw: ");
        
            String templine = input.nextLine();
            String[] templineSplit = templine.split(" ");
        
        for (int i = 0; i < hands.getDrawNum(); i++) {
            
            tempIndex[i] = (Integer.parseInt(templineSplit[i]));
        }
        tryAgain = false;
    
        for (int i = 0; i < hands.getDrawNum(); i++) {
            if(!((tempIndex[i] >= 0) && (tempIndex[i] <= 3))) {
            tryAgain = true;
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            }   
    }   
    }
    catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
        System.out.println(ime);
        System.out.println("Try again");
        tryAgain = false;
    }
    catch (IllegalArgumentException iae) {
        System.out.println(iae);
        System.out.println("Try again");
    }
    catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aiob) {
        System.out.println(aiob);
        System.out.println("Try again");
        tryAgain = false;
    }
} while(tryAgain);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `NumberFormatException` occurs when an attempt is made to convert a string with improper format into a numeric value

The only place where this can happen in your code is here

```
tempIndex[i] = (Integer.parseInt(templineSplit[i]));
```

Use a debugger or print out all values in `tempIndex` to a console to see which one is not a valid number.